# Run multiple render functions on user uploaded file simultaneously in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have multiple render functions within the R shiny code performing independent tasks (multiple output plots) on the user uploaded file. I would like all these render functions to start running in parallel when the user uploads the file. How could I do that in R shiny?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reactive` with file upload button to store a data, and call it in every `renderPlot` function :

And you should paste your code what you have done so far on Stack Overflow, it will be more easier to help:

```
df<-reactive({ read.csv(path) })
# call the csv file with df() rather than df when you use reactive to store it
output$plot1<-renderPlot({plot(df()[,1])}) 

output$plot2<-renderPlot({plot(df()[,2])})
```

Something like this

Comment: I meant to say in my previous post that I would like these renderPlot functions to run at the same time (in parallel) and not sequentially ( not wait for the first plotting job to be completed so that second plotting job starts).

Comment: That is impossible, unless you use ggplot to store all the plot invariable, and then plot it simultaneously. But it just "show the plot" simultaneously, not "draw the plot" simultaneously.

Comment: And in shiny, all the reactive object is running in parallel, just like in my answer, you will never see the second plot show after the first plot, it must be show in the same time.